# WP Как очистить от закомментированного html контент?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, что необходимо написать в `function.php`, что бы перед выводом на фронт пользователю контент очищался от строк которые были закомментированы ? От строк такого типа  `<!-- Комментарий в Php -->`

Comment: Не рассматриваете плагины для этой работы?

Comment: не, интересно как без плагинов.

Comment: Комменты из php не выводятся. Выводятся только html. Но заниматься их очисткой нафик не нужно - это абсолютно ненужный расход ресурсов.

Comment: Ага, это вы на seo продвижение таким ответом кладете. Боты читают закомиченные строки + это увеличивает объем файла отдающего пользователю. (Если это amp страница то там ещё свои ограничения накладываются). Можно конечно заворачивать комментарии в `<?php  ?>` комментарии, что б они оставались на сервере, но это так себе решение...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно сделать вот так, но нужно учитывать влияние регулярных выражений на производительность

```
add_action( 'get_header', function() {
    ob_start( function ( $buffer ) {
        return preg_replace( '/<!--(.*?)-->/s', '', $buffer );
    } );
} );

add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
    return ob_end_flush();
} );
```

Comment: а можно комментарии `<!-- ` перевести в пхп-шные `/** ` и не заниматься ерундой